# Oracle Apex - Should I create an ACL for LDAP authentication using APEX_0400 or parsing schema

Tags: oracle, acl, oracle-apex

I am not a DBA, and am having a hard time conveying the need for an ACL to allow LDAP authentication from my Oracle Apex instance out to my domain controller, which is mycompany.net port 3268.

Do I need to create the ACL and assign the ACL to the APEX_0400 user, or to the parsing schema of the application I will be using LDAP authentication for.  Is it the parsing schema which makes the LDAP request on behalf of the application, or the central APEX_0400 schema.

Or is the ACL something which is created at the instance level, i.e. it may need an owner/principle defining to own the ACL, but the ACL applies to the Oracle instance as a whole and I dont need to grant the ACL to individual Oracle schemas?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: ACls are created at database level, they can be assigned to  a schema or to public. In your case the schema will be the one that will make LDAP requests. You will not have to grant but to bound. On what oracle versione are you working?

Comment: Hi, I am using 11GR2.  I am not sure about whether to make the ACL with a PUBLIC principle or, whether to make APEX_040100 user the principle...or whether the principle of "PUBLIC" means I dont need to do specific grants to individual schemas.  I will likely have many apps, with separate APEX parsing schemas over time...and would like to avoid creating an ACL grant each time to each parsing schema and apply Oracle wide.

Answer (score 2):

Depends.

- Using the built-in LDAP authentication scheme will make it so the apex user will make the calls. Meaning you'll need to grant privileges to the correct `APEX_######` user - refer to the documentation for your version on which user this is. (4.2 = `APEX_040200`, 5 = `APEX_050000`) 
  Also read: [Enabling Network Services in Oracle Database 11g or Later (Apex 5 Docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/sec_admin_ssl.htm#HTMDB12006)
- If you want to make your own calls from the database, you'll need to grant the privilege to that user (too) (usually the parsing schema). For example, you're running some additional queries over LDAP.

Either way: the network ACL was made to increase security. If you want to set the gates wide open to allow all network traffic that's entirely your choice. I've been in a firm where there were many schema's and it's never bothered me to correctly assign the ACL privileges. It's a one-time operation usually and all changes are tracked and in a repo.
If you ever get a security audit, would it fly? Where in the network is the database? What sort of apps are hosted, are they public? Don't remove security in favour of ease-of-use.

Comment: Hi,  This is great info thanks.  If granting it to APEX_040200 will mean it works for all apps, then I dont need to do anything else in the future.  I have no need to manually query LDAP from a parsoing schema I dont think...but I guess getting more than the logon ID of the  LDAP_USER would require such a lookup?

Comment: @smackenzie The ldap auth builtin is ran from the apex user, and thus only that apex user would need a grant. Can't 100% confirm, but am quite sure!